# Upload KML file into database and display on OpenLayers Map

Tags: php, wordpress, kml, openlayers, openstreetmap

I want to create a simple form on my wordpress site so that people can upload KML files which will then be stored in the db and the route shown on on openlayers map - openstreetmap.

The project is for  a hiking site for storing hiking routes.

Any docs for this/ forums / advice. I'm completely new to this map stuff.

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of an openstreetmap with a kml overlay done in openstreetmap: http://maps.burningsilicon.net/

Before working through this example, I recommend to read some introductory documentation on openlayers, since its inner workings are not always trivial to understand.

Don't forget to put some restrictions on the uploaded kml files. You should either limit the size and/or the number of nodes, since the huge kml files generated by gps trackers can easily bog the browser down. Alternatively, you can also simplify the uploaded kml files with gpsbabel (http://www.gpsbabel.org/).

If this sounds too complicated to you, Google Maps might be an option.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the reply. I would actually like to create a portal for bikers to contribute to the opencyclemap project. I am looking into it, but I wondered if you had any experience with openstreetmap.

Comment: As of May2012 GoogleMaps interface is working very poorly with KML files.  Though it does display them, the sidebar navigation features have been disabled/changed.  hidng and displaying objects is not working and fly-to sends you 1000 mi north of the north pole.  google might or might not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have to edit the OpenStreetMap in order to make my city map a bit better and implement an on-line itinerary system. I have a KML file with all the bus stops from my city and I would like to overlay it somehow in an OSM editor program, so that I can create the streets and crosswalks in OSM accordingly. Do you have any hint

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to read this book: OpenLayers 2.10 Beginner's Guide 2011 By Erik Hazzard.

For a novice like you, this book offers a lots of documentations with appropriate example regarding KML file.

And for the database, you could use PostgreSQL 9.0. Just helping by. Good luck.